# Does $[F(\alpha_1, ... , \alpha_n) : F]$ divide $[K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) : F]$

Tags: field-theory

I know the following statement is true:

Suppose that $ [K:F] $ is finite and $ \alpha $ is algebraic over $F$. Then $[F(\alpha) : F]$ divides $[K(\alpha) : F]$

Now my question is, is the following statement true or false?

Suppose that $[K:F]$ is finite and $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ are algebraic over $F$. Then $[F(\alpha_1, ... , \alpha_n) : F]$ divides $[K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) : F]$

I tried to prove it with induction but I couldn't finish the proof, so I'm wondering if it's actually true or not. If it is true, I would appreciate help on continuing the proof below (or giving an alternate proof):

Base Case, $n = 1$: True by the original statement.

Inductive Step: Suppose that for some $ k \in \mathbb{N} $, $ \alpha_1,...,\alpha_k $ are algebraic over $ F $, that $ [F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k) : F]  $  divides  $ [K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k) : F] $.

Let $ \alpha_{k+1} $ be algebraic over $ F $

\begin{align*}
   [F(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_{k+1}) : F] 
   = [F(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_{k+1}) : F(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k)][F(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k) : F]
\end{align*}
By Tower Law. Similarly,
\begin{align*}
   [K(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_{k+1}) : F] 
   = [K(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_{k+1}) : K(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k)][K(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k) : F] 
\end{align*}
By Tower Law

I don't know how to show that
$[F(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_{k+1}) : F(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k)]$ divides $[K(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_{k+1}) : K(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k)]$ or if it can even divide it at all?

Comment: There is no need to use induction to prove your statement. Just use the tower theorem. $[K(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n):F]=[K(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n):F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)][F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n):F]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $\alpha_{i}$'s are algebraic over $F$ and as $F\subseteq K$ , they are algebraic over $K$. So  $[K(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}):F]=[K(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}):K][K:F]$ is also finite as $[K(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}):K]$ is finite.

This means

$$[K(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}):F]=[K(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}):F(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n})]\cdot [F(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}):F]$$

And hence the result follows.